# ORA-00907 error missing right parenthesis in CREATE TABLE

Tags: oracle, errors

I am getting an error as ORA-00907 (missing right parenthesis) but I think it's a generic error and not related to parentheses.

```
CREATE TABLE reservation
(
  PNRno int(9) primary key, 
  journey_date DATE, 
  no_of_seats int(8), 
  address varchar2(50), 
  contact_no int(10), 
  busno varchar2(10) references bus(busno), 
  seat_no int(25)
)
```

[image: an image of my whole code]

What exactly is the underlying error?

Comment: Judging by the error code, you're running your statements against an Oracle database, yet you have tagged your question with [tag:mysql]. Which is it? Oracle's `INT` data type does not support specifying precision.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a value after INT (e.g. `INT(8)`) does **nothing** in MySQL apart from affecting the `ZEROFILL` option. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3135854/470530) (the poster has ~ 500K rep. on StackOverflow and was MySQL Community Manager, so he probably knows what he's talking about):

> The 20 in INT(20) and BIGINT(20) means almost nothing. It's a hint for
> display width. It has nothing to do with storage, nor the range of
> values that column will accept.

This syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE bus
(
  busno VARCHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation
(
  PNRno        INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  journey_date DATE, 
  no_of_seats  INT, 
  address      VARCHAR (50), 
  contact_no   INT, 
  busno        VARCHAR (10), 
  seat_no      INT,
  
  CONSTRAINT res_bus_busno_fk FOREIGN KEY (busno) REFERENCES bus (busno)
);
```

works in both Oracle and MySQL (see the fiddles [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=53a6487e7d752d25ded9f18d150d4f4d) and [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=53a6487e7d752d25ded9f18d150d4f4d)).

A few points:

- please try and tag your questions with the correct RDBMS - some people here only answer questions on a particular server.
- you cannot just copy and paste code from one server to another - SQL has "dialects" which vary from vendor to vendor! There are some standards, but once you depart from these (as with `INT(10)` for example), you'll rapidly run into problems porting code.
- [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a6d42c35348855944fb63cc7158427e) is what happens when you put in something like `INT(10)` into an Oracle table definition which is exactly your error! Oracle's error messages are not the clearest. Check the PostgreSQL fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8a6d42c35348855944fb63cc7158427e) where the integer with zerofill error is given a line number.

  Another case in point, `VARCHAR2` (xxx) is an [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8fb0e6124f5d321b7cb4878d9b1de79f) data type and not a [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=40d31980c2205ac84059b561898202c0) one. You can see that **even** MySQL's error messages are better than Oracle's!
- please use the formatting tools for your SQL (be it DDL or DML). Having an entire table definition on one line is not great for readability! You could make your own life **much** easier by having your table defintions over multiple lines and matching brackets.
- please do not upload images for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

  Anyone reading your question who wanted to Google `ORA-00907` would have to type it in manually adding unnecessary work **and** introducing the possibility of error! There are approx. 15 other factors to consider before posting images given in the link.

Comment: What is the MySQL error that is better than Oracle's? (By the way, you've mentioned this twice.)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - MySQL [gives a line number](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=40d31980c2205ac84059b561898202c0) and shows you just before the `VARCHAR2` whereas with `INT(10)` in Oracle, [all you get](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a6d42c35348855944fb63cc7158427e) is `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` (no line number) - and the parentheses are in fact balanced. Editing out second mention - thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Oracle also gives the line number.

Comment: [Reran it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a6d42c35348855944fb63cc7158427e)  - no line number - at least not on dbfiddle... Maybe if you're running it locally?

Comment: No, dbfidddle does not display the full error details. I don't see how that is Oracle's fault.